# Is is possible to use the server side on the C# with a dialog button

Tags: javascript, .net, dialog

What I am trying to do is popup a div includes two buttons for the feedback. One button is for the cancellation and the other one is for the submission( using server side).

```
HTML

<div id="message" style="display:none">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClearButton.png"
     onclick="ImageButton1_Click1"/>
</div>

JAVASCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*$('div#message').dialog({ autoOpen: false })*/
        $('#hlfeedback').click(function () {
            $('div#message').dialog({
                width: 608,
                height: 750,
                modal: true,
                overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
                buttons: {},
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                }
            });
        });
        $('#ImageButton1').click(function () {
            $('div#message').dialog({
                close: function (event, ui) { $(this).close(); }
            });
        });
    })</script>

Server Side

protected void ImageButton1_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Not working 
}
```

The server side is not working at all. as well as the close button using the javascript.
I want to submit a from using a button in the server side to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Server-side events working you need the dialog to be a child of the `<form runat='server'>` tag (which is usually on every aspx page).

When creating a dialog using jQuery it isn't automatically added as child of the `form` and therefore your server side code isn't being called.

This can easily be fixed, add: `$(this).parent().appendTo("form");`  to the dialog's open function, e.g.:

```
$('div#message').dialog({
        width: 608,
        height: 750,
        modal: true,
        overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
        buttons: {},
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        }
});
```